# Scrapy not passing scraped urls from parse to callback

Tags: python, scrapy

`Parse_brand` is the problem. It returns nothing and is currently scraping no urls, even though parse works perfectly and should be feeding it over 4,000 urls. I'm new to scrapy; the docs were unhelpful. Any thoughts?

I confirmed the parse method works by making it yield a dictionary of data from the scraped page, including the href attributes that I wanted. I then wrote a simple request that I hoped would tell the spider to follow every URL it found, and then call the `parse_brand` function to pull more url's from those pages. The out put from the callback is empty dicts of the form `{'f':[]}`.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from collections import deque

class PageContentLink(Item):
    url = Field()

class FragranceSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "number5"

    start_urls = ['http://www.basenotes.net/brand/']
    allowed_domains = ['basenotes.net']


    def parse(self, response):
        all_brand_links = response.xpath('//*[@id="contentbn"]/div[4]/div/ul/li')
        for brand in all_brand_links:
            if brand.xpath('.//a[2]'):
                href = brand.xpath('.//a[2]/@href').extract_first()
            else:
                href = brand.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(href, callback=self.parse_brand)

    def parse_brand(self, response):
        fragrance_link = response.xpath('//*[@id="contentbn"]/div[6]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/h3/a/@href').extract_first()
        yield {'f': fragrance_link}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy **is** passing your function as a callback function. However, if you check your `fragrance_link` you will find out that it doesn't hold any value. I couldn't figure out what you are trying to extract here.

Edit:

I am sorry to tell you that you cant extract that. If you see the HTML page of that link. you will find this div that has this id `div-gpt-ad-1433423286798-2`. Above, you can find that they are using google services to push this data. If you try to extract any data about that div (or the green line). you can extract it. Anything below the green line or that Id will not be extracted. Since the content is being loaded by JS. I will advice you to try Selenium

Comment: Parse finds urls that look like this http://www.basenotes.net/fragrancedirectory/?house=100361 On those pages, I want to apply the xpath that should return a fragrance_link. As you can see, on that particular page, the expath would return 80 such links, I'm asking only for the first here because it's not working.

Comment: @Ryan check my edit, please. It took me some time to figure this out :)

Comment: Thank you. I was beginning to question my life choices. XD